# How can I use psycopg2.extras in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I want to upload a huge number of entries (~600k) into a simple table in a PostgreSQL DB, with one foreign key, a timestamp and 3 float per each entry. However, it takes 60 ms per each entry to execute the core bulk insert described [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow), thus the whole execution would take 10 h. I have found out, that it is a performance issue of `executemany()` method, however it has been solved with the `execute_values()` method in [psycopg2 2.7](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers).

The code I run is the following:

```
#build a huge list of dicts, one dict for each entry
engine.execute(SimpleTable.__table__.insert(),
               values) # around 600k dicts in a list
```

I see that it is a common problem, however I have not managed to find a solution in sqlalchemy itself. Is there any way to tell sqlalchemy to call `execute_values()` in some occasions? Is there any other way to implement huge inserts without constructing the SQL statements by myself?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was about to suggest using `SimpleTable.__table__.insert().values(values)`, which would compile to a single INSERT statement with multiple VALUES tuples, but it turned out that it was actually even slower on my machine. The compiling itself was as slow as using your method that relies on `executemany()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the answer you are looking for in the sense that this does not address attempting to instruct SQLAlchemy to use the psycopg extras, and requires – sort of – manual SQL, but: you can access the underlying psycopg connections from an engine with [`raw_connection()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.raw_connection), which allows using [COPY FROM](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from):

```
import io
import csv
from psycopg2 import sql

def bulk_copy(engine, table, values):
    csv_file = io.StringIO()
    headers = list(values[0].keys())
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, headers)
    writer.writerows(values)

    csv_file.seek(0)

    # NOTE: `format()` here is *not* `str.format()`, but
    # `SQL.format()`. Never use plain string formatting.
    copy_stmt = sql.SQL("COPY {} (" +
                        ",".join(["{}"] * len(headers)) +
                        ") FROM STDIN CSV").\
        format(sql.Identifier(str(table.name)),
               *(sql.Identifier(col) for col in headers))

    # Fetch a raw psycopg connection from the SQLAlchemy engine
    conn = engine.raw_connection()
    try:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.copy_expert(copy_stmt, csv_file)

        conn.commit()

    except:
        conn.rollback()
        raise

    finally:
        conn.close()
```

and then

```
bulk_copy(engine, SimpleTable.__table__, values)
```

This should be plenty fast compared to executing INSERT statements. Moving 600,000 records on this machine took around 8 seconds, ~13µs/record. You could also use the raw connections and cursor with the extras package.

Answer (score 8):

Meanwhile it became possible (from SqlAlchemy 1.2.0) with the `use_batch_mode` flag on the `create_engine()` function. See the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-connect-arguments). It uses the `execute_batch()` function from `psycopg.extras`.

Comment: And they've expanded their support for the fast execution helpers even more: "Changed in version 1.3.7: the `use_batch_mode` flag has been superseded by a new parameter `executemany_mode` which provides support both for psycopg2’s `execute_batch` helper as well as the `execute_values` helper." https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-fast-execution-helpers

Comment: And since 1.4, `values_only` is the default. The psycopg2 execute_values() extension is used for qualifying INSERT statements, which rewrites the INSERT to include multiple VALUES clauses so that many parameter sets can be inserted with one statement.