# Optimizing bulk update with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am having trouble with a performance bottleneck trying to update many records across two tables at once. Currently, I have some Pandas DataFrames (`new_records_df` and `modified_records_df`) containing the records I would like to insert / update. See the following psuedocode:

```
if not new_records_df.empty:
    new_recs_data = new_records_df.T.to_dict().values()  # creates a list of dictionaries from the DataFrame
    new_recs = []
    for r in new_recs_data:
        new_rec = {'foo_id': foo_id,
                   'bar': bar}
        new_recs.append(new_rec)
    db_session.bulk_insert_mappings(Record, new_recs, return_defaults=True) # return_defaults inserts the id of the inserted record into the dictionary object
    new_related_recs = []
    for nr in new_recs:
        new_related_rec = {'rec_id': nr['id'],
                           'baz': baz}
        new_related_recs.append(new_rec)
    db_session.bulk_insert_mappings(RelatedRec, new_related_recs)

if not modified_records_df.empty:
    modified_rec_data = modified_records_df.T.to_dict().values()  # again, converting teh DataFrame to a list of dicts
    modified_recs = []
    for m in modified_rec_data:
        modified_rec = {'id': m['id'],
                        'zab': zab}
        modified_recs.append(modified_rec)
    db_session.bulk_update_mappings(RelatedRec, modified_recs)  # when a record is modified, only the RelatedRec object is updated. The Record object already exists and stays unmodified
```

problem is, with ~8k records the looping over the dictionaries takes ~20 seconds, while the actual insert / update of the database only takes about 4 seconds. I was hoping that there is a clever way that I can eliminate the `for` loop since this appears to be the bottleneck. My database is postgres and my driver is `psycoppg2 2.6.2`

Comment: I construct a string that is the entire query.. then pass that.  I regularly pass queries that 10 to 12 thousand lines long.

Comment: Have you read the performance notes on using [`return_defaults=True`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_insert_mappings.params.return_defaults)? If enabled insertions happen **one-by-one**.  In general [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow) should be an interesting read for you. You could also [use the COPY statement of Postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317376/how-can-i-use-psycopg2-extras-in-sqlalchemy/43321119#43321119).