# How to create a table in one DB from the result of a query from different DB in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, cx-oracle

I'm working with two separate databases (Oracle and PostgreSQL) where a substantial amount of reference data is in Oracle that I'll frequently need to reference while doing analysis on data stored in Postgres (I have no control over this part).  I'd like to be able to directly transfer the results of a query from Oracle to a table in Postgres (and vice versa).  The closest I've gotten is something like the code below using Pandas as a go between, but it's quite slow.

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import cx_Oracle
import sqlalchemy

# CONNECT TO POSTGRES
db__PG = psycopg2.connect(dbname="username", user="password")
eng_PG = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/db_one')

# CONNECT TO ORACLE
db__OR = cx_Oracle.connect('username', 'password', 'SID_Name')
eng_OR = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://username:password@10.1.2.3:4422/db_two')

#DEFINE QUERIES
query_A = "SELECT * FROM tbl_A"
query_B = "SELECT * FROM tbl_B"

# CREATE PANDAS DATAFRAMES FROM QUERY RESULTS
df_A = pd.read_sql_query(query_A, db__OR)
df_B = pd.read_sql_query(query_B, db__PG)

# CREATE TABLES FROM PANDAS DATAFRAMES
df_A.to_sql(name='tbl_a', con=eng_PG, if_exists='replace', index=False)
df_B.to_sql(name='tbl_b', con=eng_OR, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

I think there would have to be a more efficient, direct way to do this (like database links for moving data across different DB's in Oracle), but I'm fairly new to Python and have generally worked either directly in SQL or in SAS previously.  I've been searching for ways to create a table directly from a python cursor result or a SQLAlchemy ResultProxy, but haven't had much luck.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at Postgresql's [foreign data wrappers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers), which include a database wrapper for Oracle. With that you could simply present your Oracle tables as foreign tables in Postgresql. No manual transfer required! This of course would require that the Postgresql DB can connect to the Oracle one.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea, I actually came across that same idea elsewhere shortly after posting this question and have been looking into it.  At this point I'm having trouble compiling the oracle fdw, but I'm still fairly early on in the process.  If I can get it to work I think it might fit the bill, although I'm still somewhat surprised I haven't been able to find a better way to do it with Python or SQLAlchemy.

Comment: In case of dumping stuff to Postgresql in Python you'll be better served by psycopg2's [`Cursor.copy_from()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) and [`Cursor.copy_expert()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert). [Here's an example of accessing the underlying psycopg2 connection from SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317376/how-can-i-use-psycopg2-extras-in-sqlalchemy/43321119#43321119). I'd skip using pandas as the middle-man entirely.

Comment: I'll definitely look into that. Thanks!!