# SQLAlchemy "excluded" PostgreSQL namespace in INSERT ... ON CONFLICT

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I can't find a way to execute PostgreSQL INSERT .. ON UPDATE through SQLAlchemy.
Is there a way to do it with multiple rows, performing the operation on the whole data at once?

I try to upsert with values from a pandas dataframe:

```
for insert_values in df.to_dict(orient='records'):
    insert_statement = sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.insert(orders_to_channels).values(insert_values)
    upsert_statement = insert_statement.on_conflict_do_update(
        constraint='orders_to_channels_pkey',
    set_=insert_values
    conn.execute(upsert)
```

This works on a  row basis and as every row is handled separately - it works terribly slow (20 minutes for 7000 rows).
Is there a way to perform this operation as a single SQL statement?

I am looking for some kind of an opportunity to pass parameters like `{'column_name':'excluded .column_name'}` to the update part of the statement, where "excluded" won't be parsed as a part of the string value, but rather as a SQL literal. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the special alias [`excluded`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.dml.Insert.excluded) of the [`postgresql.dml.Insert`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.dml.Insert) object:

```
insert_statement = sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.insert(orders_to_channels)
upsert_statement = insert_statement.on_conflict_do_update(
    constraint='orders_to_channels_pkey',
    set_={ 'column_name': insert_statement.excluded.column_name }
)
insert_values = df.to_dict(orient='records')
conn.execute(upsert_statement, insert_values)
```

Note that [psycopg2's `executemany()` is essentially equivalent to `execute()` in a loop](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany), so you might not see as big a performance upgrade as expected. You could try using the ["multiple values" syntax](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.values.params.*args):

```
insert_values = df.to_dict(orient='records')
insert_statement = sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.insert(orders_to_channels).values(insert_values)
...
```

But, [that might not be any faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317376/how-can-i-use-psycopg2-extras-in-sqlalchemy/43321119#comment73706472_43317376).

Comment: if you want the whole thing inserted, change the corresponding line to set_=insert_statement.excluded