# ProgrammingError - sqlalchemy - on_conflict_do_update

Tags: sqlalchemy

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49727254/5665430):

As Ilja Everilä mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49732953/5665430), I created a table object:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
metadata = MetaData()
idTagTable = Table('id_tag', metadata,
                 Column('id', String(255), primary_key = True),     
                 Column('category', String(20), nullable = False),
                 Column('createddate', Date, nullable = False),
                 Column('updatedon', Date, nullable = False)
                 )
```

After creating a table object, I changed insert and update statements:

```
insert_statement = sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.insert(idTagTable)
upsert_statement = insert_statement.on_conflict_do_update(
        constraint=PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
        set_={"updatedon": insert_statement.excluded.updateon,
              "category":insert_statement.excluded.category}
)
insert_values = df.to_dict(orient='records')
conn.execute(upsert_statement, insert_values)
```

Now I am getting Programming Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-66-0fc6a1bf9c6b>", line 7, in <module>
conn.execute(upsert_statement, insert_values)

File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 945, in execute
return meth(self, multiparams, params)

File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)

File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
compiled_sql, distilled_params

File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
context)

File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1402, in _handle_dbapi_exception
exc_info

File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)

File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1159, in _execute_context
context)

File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 467, in do_executemany
cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)

ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near 
")"
LINE 1: ...category) VALUES ('sports') ON CONFLICT () DO UPDAT...
                                                    ^
```

Not Able to understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`PrimaryKeyConstraint`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.PrimaryKeyConstraint) object you're using as [`constraint=`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.dml.Insert.on_conflict_do_update.params.constraint) argument is not bound to any table and would seem to produce nothing when rendered, as seen in `ON CONFLICT ()`. Instead pass the primary key(s) of your table as the *conflict_target* and Postgresql will perform unique index inference:

```
upsert_statement = insert_statement.on_conflict_do_update(
        constraint=idTagTable.primary_key,
        set_={"updatedon": insert_statement.excluded.updateon,
              "category":insert_statement.excluded.category}
)
```