# Timescaledb: get first value before and after range

Tags: timescaledb

Given a time series range with values v0-v5 stored at **irregular** intervals in timescaledb.

```
v0     v1    v2   v3   v4 
t0 - t1 - t2 - t3 - t4 - t5
```

A range starting from >=t2 and to <=t4 is selected resulting in getting v2 and v3.

```sql
select time from table where time >= t2 and time <=t4 order by ASC
```

In addition I would like to get the first after and the first before the range so v1 and v4. The values are uneven so I do not know at what time t1 or t4 are. Could be a millisecond or years.

Not tested, but I assume could I could do this as explained in [TimescaleDB: efficiently select last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575004/timescaledb-efficiently-select-last-row)

v1

```sql
select time from table where time < t2 order by desc LIMIT 1
```

v4

```sql
select time from table where time > t4 order by asc LIMIT 1
```

But this requires doing three queries, is there a way(s) to make it more efficient in timescaledb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use subqueries to achieve this: (example query with range of `'2021-04-01 04:04:00'` - `'2021-04-01 04:07:00'`)

```sql
SELECT time FROM table
WHERE 
    (time >= timestamp '2021-04-01 04:04:00' AND time <= timestamp '2021-04-01 04:07:00')
    OR time = (SELECT time FROM table WHERE time < timestamp '2021-04-01 04:04:00' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1)
    OR time = (SELECT time FROM table WHERE time > timestamp '2021-04-01 04:07:00' ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY time
```