# Doing a bulk copy of dictionary list to postgres using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a list of dictionary `list_dict` like the one below:

```
[{u'default_bhp': False, u'price_period': u'Monthly'},{u'default_bhp': False, u'price_period': u'Yearly'}]
```

At the moment I am inserting this to my db using:

```
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute(ModelClass.__table__.insert(), list_dict)
```

I just wanted to check if there is a faster way to insert data to the database, because I have a huge amount of data.

Can we use a bulk `copy` or something here?

How to use `use_batch_mode` functionality?? Something like below:

```
 engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost/test_db', use_batch_mode=True)
conn = engine.connect()
    conn.execute_batch(ModelClass.__table__.insert(), list_dict)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317376/how-can-i-use-psycopg2-extras-in-sqlalchemy. Either use `COPY`, or enable the new `use_batch_mode` flag when creating the engine, which should speed up your existing code, maybe.

Comment: How to use the `use_batch_mode` ? I have updated my question. Is it used this way with list of dict?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-connect-arguments, simply pass `use_batch_mode=True` to `create_engine`. It'll use it for DB-API `executemany()` calls, which you are doing (under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [bulk_insert_mappings](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_insert_mappings) (if you don't know about this already), this is probably closest to what you want to achieve.

But if you're actually have *a lot* of data, eager unpacking into list of dicts may be not the good way to go, so you may need grouper/chunk management on top of bulk_insert

Comment: I am iterating through a pandas dataframe row by row , checking for some validation and then writing that frame.to_dict() and then appending to my list_dict. Outside the loop, I am doing bulk insert mentioned in the question. Any suggestion on this. Meantime, I am reading on `bulk_insert_mappings`.

Comment: If you need to validate date per row, I have no idea how you can speed this up. Way to go is (probably) — process your rows (get + validate + add to list) in batches of ~1000, than make bulk insert. The only thing you can optimise easily here is network roundtrip — with bulk save.

Comment: can you provide a code snippet example how to achieve this.