# AWS Postgres inserts with SQLALchemy more than 1000 times slower than local SQLite

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy

I have a Postgres (10.2) Server on AWS RDS (m4.large 2vCPU, 8GB memory) with standard settings (except synchronous commits being off) and any kind of SQLALchemy inserts are incredibly slow in comparison to a local SQLite on my laptop.

I ran the performance script found in the [official SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/performance.html), see bottom of the page.

Basically, what the script does is create a table `Customer` that has a primary integer key `id` and a string column `name`. The script simply calls `"INSERT INTO customer (name) VALUES (?)"` in various ways to insert 1000 rows.

And the results are really devastating for the AWS setup that costs almost 200 USD a month:

**SQLite results**:

SQLAlchemy ORM: Total time for 1000 records 0.17040562629699707 secs

SQLAlchemy ORM pk given: Total time for 1000 records 0.08621740341186523 secs

SQLAlchemy ORM bulk_save_objects(): Total time for 1000 records 0.027913570404052734 secs

SQLAlchemy ORM bulk_insert_mappings(): Total time for 1000 records 0.014255523681640625 secs

SQLAlchemy Core: Total time for 1000 records **0.010448455810546875 secs**

**AWS Postgres results**:

SQLAlchemy ORM: Total time for 1000 records 18.51957869529724 secs

SQLAlchemy ORM pk given: Total time for 1000 records 18.049689054489136 secs

SQLAlchemy ORM bulk_save_objects(): Total time for 1000 records 18.0506489276886 secs

SQLAlchemy ORM bulk_insert_mappings(): Total time for 1000 records 17.969014644622803 secs

SQLAlchemy Core: Total time for 1000 records **22.948890209197998 secs**

All insertion methods are so much slower, the core one even by more than 1000 times. Is this a Postgres configuration issue? My network latency cannot be that bad :-). Thanks!

## EDIT:

Thanks to @Laurenz, I used `pg_stat_statements` to investigate and the query times are completely fine. I suspect it is a networking issue. Moreover, I started a small EC2 instance in the same VPC as the Database and ran the performance script again: There the performance is orders of magnitudes better (only about 5-20 times slower than SQLite, but this is what I expected).

Any idea how to solve this networking issue? What can be a reason for this? I mean 1000 rows with a bit of string data is not a lot in terms of bytes that need to be transferred over the internet. Anyone else who came across the same issue with AWS DBs living in a VPC?

Comment: As a first step, you'll have to identify the exact SQL statements that cause the slowdown. For that, use `pg_stat_statements` or pgBadger. If the slowdown is not caused by the database, continue searching in the application server layer. If you can identify problem SQL statements, run them with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` and add the query and the plan to the question. Otherwise it is impossible to help.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing special about the inserts and the SQL statements, they are just inserting single rows consisting of just two columns an integer id (primary key) and string name. It's the simple script provided by the SQLALchemy library (see the link to the docs) to test performance. It boils down to really just `"INSERT INTO customer (name) VALUES (?)"` and nothing more.

Comment: Great. If you know that it is only this statement, gather statistics with `pg_stat_statements`, run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` and add both to the question. Profile your application to see where the time is spent.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. See the above edit, the query times are completely fine, it is a networking issue :-/. Any more ideas about that? :-D

Comment: Great! Finding the problem is the first step. The many client-server round trips are killing you. Can you use `COPY` to efficiently insert many rows at once?

Comment: I'd rather not `COPY`, the production environment will run in the same VPC, this is more about developing on my local machine and do some functional/integration tests against the (staging) database. So I don't want to use other means of data input than what is used in production and I don't want to complicate the data input for code simplicity. Any idea how SQLalchemy could be configured to avoid these roundtrips on bulk inserts before using the last resort of low level `COPY` statements?

Comment: No, I'm out of my depth here. PostgreSQL has multi-row inserts: `INSERT INTO tab VALUES (...), (...), (...)`, but that's a non-standard feature.

Comment: The anwer is simple: dont do bulk-inserts using Row-At-A-Time processing. It will cost you one or two network round-trips, plus a couple of system calls/context-switches **per record**. Oh, and the parsing+execution/committing of the actual SQL.

Comment: The usual DB-API drivers for Postgresql implement `executemany` basically as a loop and separate inserts. `psycopg2` has some methods to speed up bulk inserts. Try creating your engine with `use_batch_mode=True`: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-batch-mode-fast-execution

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317376/how-can-i-use-psycopg2-extras-in-sqlalchemy