# Multiple inserts at a time using SQLAlchemy with Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

My current single insert code is:

```
def add_item(a_email,a_first,a_last,a_address,a_tag):
    query = db.insert(table_items).values(email=a_email,firstname=a_first,lastname=a_last,address=a_address,tag=a_tag)
    connection.execute(query)
```

Problem is, I'm inserting millions of entries and it's taking a LONG time doing it one by one. What is the best way to insert, say, 10 entries at a time? Say I have a list:

```
my_items = []
my_items.append(["test@test.com","John","Doe","1234 1st Street","Tag1"])
```

Pretend I appended 10 items into my_items, how can I get all of them into my Postgres database in one go?

Comment: You should consider using `COPY` instead of inserts.

Comment: Some pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125236/sqlalchemy-psycopg2-and-postgresql-copy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317376/how-can-i-use-psycopg2-extras-in-sqlalchemy. Another option is `use_batch_mode`: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-connect-arguments, which will handle issuing multiple inserts in a single roundtrip for you, if using `executemany` style (passing multiple values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using insert from `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql` , you will need to pass a list of dictionaries ( with key-value corresponding to your column_name and the data for that row. it basically converts it to a single insert statement for all your rows. 
An example would be

````
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert```
...
Data=[{'column1':value1},{'column1':valu1}]
stmt=insert(Table,Data)
db.session().execute(stmt)
````

As mentioned in the comment you can also use the `COPY` command

Comment: No need to import it specifically from the dialect. The "plain" inserts support multiple values, if the dialect in use supports it.

Comment: Hmm this almost worked for me, but it's asking me for 'id' (which is just the primary key). But I don't ever provide the primary key - I always let it be automatically generated. How can I use this method but not provide a column?

Comment: @Max , you have to remove the column from your dictionary.